# On raspberry my script breaking after looping some time when there was no input stream

Tags: linux, bash, shell, raspberry-pi3, omxplayer

On raspberry my script breaking after looping some time when there was no input stream

[image]#! /bin/sh

```sh
clear

echo -n "Box ID: " ;  sudo cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep Serial | cut -d ' ' -f 2

sleep 2

ping -c1 -s1 www.google.com
pingStatus=$?

if [ $pingStatus = "0" ]

then

clear

echo -n "Box ID:" ; sudo cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep Serial | cut -d ' ' -f 2

echo "Downloading Channel Link"    

RTMP="rtmp://localhost:1935/live/mystream"    

omxplayer  --no-keys  $RTMP

./myscript.sh

else

clear

echo "Internet Status: False"
echo -n "Box ID: " ; sudo cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep Serial | cut -d ' ' -f 2
echo "Internet disconnected. Please check Internet"

sleep 1

echo "Starting Channel Promo"

sleep 1

omxplayer --o hdmi  /home/pi/promo.mp4

./myscript.sh

fi
```

Comment: What is the purpose of your code? Help us help you.

Comment: Is your script recursively calling itself? If so, use `exec ./myscript.sh` so that you only have one version executing at a time.

Comment: @Yonlif When the internet is true, it should play my rtmp link and when the internet goes off it should play my promo, after completing promo it should start internet check again. When My streaming offline it just looping my script recursively, then the error coming

Answer (score 0):

Try to start your script using:

```
bash -x script_name.sh
```

and look for errors in the output.

Comment: It's changed total output of my script

Answer (score 0):

The '-x' option will turn debug on, and output everything you script does.
If you cannot interpret it, you can paste it here.

The problem may not be with script itself, but the application dying after 
a while. Which can be perfectly normal, or due to a running exception.

You can catch output of the omxplayer like:

```
omxplayer --no-keys $RTMP 2 > &1 > /var/log/omxplayer.log
```

This will catch stdout and stderr output. If you cannot interpret it, you will have to RTFM.